# how to save list view state and get back to that state

Tags: java, android, mysql

i am getting data from MySQL database in JSON form and showing in custom list view.list view is very lengthy. now i want that when i click on button in main activity it redirect me to the list view to the same position where i have left.
thanks in advance.

```
    public class ShowParahDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
ProgressDialog pd;
CustomAdapter c;
ArrayList<Ayah_textAR> ar_ayahAR;
ArrayList<Ayah_textTR> ar_ayah_TR;
JazzyListView lv;
String intent_parah_ID;
String intent_parahName;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_parah_detail);
    intent_parah_ID=getIntent().getExtras().getString("parahID");
    intent_parahName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("parahName");
    setTitle(intent_parahName);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(ShowParahDetail.this, R.style.pdtheme);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
    pd.show();
    lv= (JazzyListView) findViewById(R.id.lvparahDetail);

    ar_ayahAR = new ArrayList<>();
    ar_ayah_TR = new ArrayList<>();
    ShowDataAR();
    ShowTranslationUR();
}

private void ShowTranslationUR() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String RecievedString = "";
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("parahid", intent_parah_ID);
            Network network = new Network("showParahTranslationUR.php", params);

            try {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                RecievedString = network.ToRecieveDataFromWeb();
                JsonParsing jsonparsing = new JsonParsing(RecievedString);
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> convertedarraydata = jsonparsing.ParsejsonArray(RecievedString);
                for (int i = 0; i < convertedarraydata.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> positionHashmap;
                    positionHashmap = convertedarraydata.get(i);

                    String str_ayahText = positionHashmap.get("verseText");
                    String str_verseID = positionHashmap.get("verse_id");
                    String str_surahID = positionHashmap.get("surah_id");


                    Ayah_textTR ayahTR = new Ayah_textTR();
                    ayahTR.ayah_textTR = str_ayahText;
                    ayahTR.verse_id = str_verseID;
                    ayahTR.surah_id = str_surahID;
                    ar_ayah_TR.add(ayahTR);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void ShowDataAR() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String RecievedString = "";
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("parahid", intent_parah_ID);
            Network network = new Network("showParahDetails.php", params);

            try {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                RecievedString = network.ToRecieveDataFromWeb();
                JsonParsing jsonparsing = new JsonParsing(RecievedString);
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> convertedarraydata = jsonparsing.ParsejsonArray(RecievedString);
                for (int i = 0; i < convertedarraydata.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> positionHashmap;
                    positionHashmap = convertedarraydata.get(i);
                    String str_ayahID = positionHashmap.get("verse_id");
                    String str_ayahText = positionHashmap.get("verseText");

                    Ayah_textAR ayahText = new Ayah_textAR();
                    ayahText.ayah_id = str_ayahID;
                    ayahText.ayah_textAR = str_ayahText;
                    ar_ayahAR.add(ayahText);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (ShowParahDetail.this == null)
                    return;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Parcelable state = lv.onSaveInstanceState();
                        lv.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
                        c = new CustomAdapter(ShowParahDetail.this, R.layout.cstm_parah, R.id.tv_parahNAME, ar_ayahAR);
                        lv.setAdapter(c);
                        if(pd!=null){
                            pd.dismiss();
                            pd = null;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();
}


class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ayah_textAR> {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Ayah_textAR> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cstm_ayah, parent, false);

        final TextView tv_ayah_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_ayahText);
        final TextView tv_ayahTR = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_ayahTR);

        try {
            Ayah_textAR ayah = ar_ayahAR.get(position);
            tv_ayah_text.setText(ayah.ayah_id + " : " + ayah.ayah_textAR);
            Ayah_textTR parahTR = ar_ayah_TR.get(position);
            tv_ayahTR.setText(parahTR.ayah_textTR);
        }catch (Exception e){
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        });
        return v;
    }
}
public class Ayah_textAR {
    String ayah_id;
    String ayah_textAR;
}
public class Ayah_textTR {
    String verse_id;
    String ayah_textTR;
    String surah_id;
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (pd != null) {
        pd.dismiss();
        pd = null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: don't finish your list activity when you intent to other activity. And when you want to back list activity, just call onBackPressed() when you click button.

Comment: Yes, @JavadKhan is right, Just don't finish your list activity.

Comment: i have three activity A, B and C. i have list view in B activity and also in C activity. when i pressed button in A activityB activity opens and load data in list view and on item click C activity opens and load data in list view. i want that if i am in C activity on 30th position in listview and go back to A activity   now if i press resume button i want to show the C activity 30th position

Answer (score 0):

You have three activities, A,B and C. Start your activity B with Intent. And also start your activity C with intent. Then, if you start your activity A and wish to save data which are exist in C, then start your activity A with intent. And don't finish your activity C. And if you want to resume activity C, just call `onBackPressed()` from your activity A. Don't forget finishing your activity A. For this call `onFinish()`.

Comment: Activity A is main activity. and every time activity C loaded with different data defended on the item clicked in B activity.

Comment: If you want to open activity A from activity C, you should do like that. When you call onBackPressed() it resumes your activity C. But if you want to call activity C from activity B, just recreate activity C with intent.

Comment: if close the app permanent and reopen it then how can i access activity C from A with previous state?

Comment: if you close your app, it depends on your memory limit. Android OS manipulate this. If you not clean your app from RAM, it just adds your app to backstack. And if you reopen app in few time, it just resume Activity A and when you click to back, it resume your activity C. Get mor information about activity lifecycle:  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: i know that but it is not a solution. i need to save the state of list view. and want to get back on button click from main activity.

Comment: for saving state, there are two methods in activity: onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) . There are lots of solutions for saving state. From native platform methods to own algorithms. Just learn about activity lifecycle.

Comment: i have tried a lot of solution but not working. can you give me some code for that.